# Clojure: Write a Clojure function that returns a list of all 2^n bits strings of length n

Tags: string, recursion, clojure

I want to write a Clojure function called (nbits n) that returns a list of all 2^n bits strings of length n.

My expected output is:

```
user=> (nbits -2)
()

user=> (nbits 0)
()

user=> (nbits 1)
((0) (1))

user=> (nbits 2)
((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))

user=> (nbits 3)
((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
```

Here is my try:

```
(defn add0 [seq] 
  (cond (empty? seq) 'nil
        (and (seq? seq) (> (count seq) 0)) 
          (cons (cons '0 (first seq)) (add0 (rest seq)))))

(defn add1 [seq]
  (cond (empty? seq) 'nil
        (and (seq? seq) (> (count seq) 0)) 
          (cons (cons '1 (first seq)) (add1 (rest seq)))))

(defn nbits [n]
  (cond (number? n) 
          (cond (< n 1) '()
                (= n 1) '((0) (1))
                (> n 1) 
                  (list (add0 (nbits (- n 1))) (add1 (nbits (- n 1))))) 
        :else 'nil))
```

But the output is not right. Where did I go wrong? I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I've re-indented your code to a more conventional style so that others might read it. If you feel this is too radical of an edit, then feel free to roll-back. I recommend using a Clojure/Lisp friendly editor.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this (lazily and iteratively) with the [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) library:

```
user=> (defn nbits [n] 
         (if (pos? n) 
           (clojure.math.combinatorics/selections [0 1] n) 
           '()))
#'user/nbits
user=> (nbits 0)
()
user=> (nbits 1)
((0) (1))
user=> (nbits 2)
((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))
user=> (nbits 3)
((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
```

This version has the advantage of leveraging iteration to avoid blowing the stack (which I got at n=14 with the original version on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is to replace `list` with `concat` in your `nbits`. Your `add0` and `add1` both return a list of "bit" lists, so creating a list of these two lists of lists adds one too many levels of list nesting. You want to concatenate the results of `add0` and `add1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another take is to just iterate over numbers and convert each number to a sequence rather than reimplementing addition.

```
(defn nbits [n] 
  (for [m (range (Math/pow 2 n))]
    (map #(if (bit-test m %) 1 0) (range (dec n) -1 -1))))
```